# Unknown column in 'field list' without referencing that column

Tags: mysql

first post. Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong. I looked around a bit and saw similar issues but none quite so odd, imo.

I'm trying to execute

```
INSERT INTO product (uuid, productNumber, status)
    (SELECT uuid, productNumber, status
     FROM new_product new)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE product.status = new.status;
```

And get the error `Unknown column 'p.id' in 'field list'`

I'm not using anything like p.id, but the `product` and `new_product` tables both have an id column that I'm deliberately not referencing. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? It seems to work for some records but not others. Originally was calling using SQLAlchemy, but reproduced in regular MySQL.

`new_product` is a table I create as part of the script. It has almost all the same fields as product, and is generated using pandas `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql()`.

EDIT: Thanks for the suggestions. It turned out to be a trigger someone else had edited that I wasn't able to see. Silly

Comment: The error suggests it is coming from some other query than the one you show.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It happens even when that's the only query in the console at all. There aren't any triggers on the database, but is it possible this is causing some other query to run?

Comment: @AndrewWatton Please [edit] your question to include the description of `new_product`. Is that a view?